Replace 14-30R with 6-30R
I have a NEMA 14-30R outlet in my garage and would like to plug in a garage heater that has a NEMA 6-30 plug (without using a separate adaptor, as the heater instructions advise against this).  Since the 14-30 and 6-30 are both 240v/30 amp, can I just change out my 14-30 outlet for a 6-30, or is there something I’m missing?

Replace the 6-30 plug with 14-30P. Nothing connects to the neutral wire.  Field-installed plugs are legal (for an appliance which is permitted to be cord-and-plug connected).

That should be perfectly fine. Replace with a 6-30 and cap the white neutral wire with a wire nut.
If you expect to have any future use for the 14-30 (and don't say "for EV charging", because for that (a) hardwired is better and (b) if you do go with a receptacle, you should be able to get a 6-30 cable for EV charging, except that very oddly Tesla offers 6-20 and 6-50 (which also works for 40A) but not 6-30...), you could actually wire up a second receptacle. Just like ordinary 15A and 20A 120V circuits can have multiple receptacles, larger circuits such as 240V 30A can too.
But if you do that, I would put the 6-30 and 14-30 right next to each other. Both because it is easiest that way (replace a small box with a big box or put a second box right next to the first box) and also because that way it is easy to make sure you never use both receptacles at the same time. With 15A/20A 120V receptacle most loads (except heaters, toasters, hair dryers, etc.) use only a tiny fraction of the rated capacity, most 30A devices will use, pretty much by definition, something more than 16A, typically more than 20A, so running two on one circuit at the same time doesn't turn out well - leading to breaker trips (safe but annoying) or overloads (not safe, and quite problematic if that starts a fire).

IMO the second two paragraphs are not useful.  What are we taking about besides a dryer?  There is no practical use case for sharing a circuit with a dryer.  It doesn't make sense and there is no other dual voltage 30A appliance.  Certainly not sharing it with a heater in the same room.  So you can only heat the room when you're not using it :(

@jay613 There must have been some reason there was a 14-30 in the first place. We don't know what that is.

Big ol' UPS for your bitcoin mining operation. A dryer may be the most common thing with a NEMA 14-30P on it, but it's hardly the ONLY thing.

I don't think you want a heater for your crypto farm any more than you want to timeshare room comfort and dry clothing.   Still, @Ecnerwal your general point is valid, but I still think the answer was better after the first sentence.   And if you are timesharing the outlet, the best approach is probably a 14-30 plug for the heater.  $20, 5 minutes work, and it prevents simultaneous use.

Just speculating what it might have been put in by prior owner for. If you have an active  bitcoin operation, it should be taking the place of your furnace all winter, IMHO.

Appreciate the quick responses, thanks much!
